# Let $f:]0,1]\to \mathbb R$ a continuous function s.t $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ exist. Show that $\int_0^1\hat f=\int_{o^+}^1 f.$

Tags: integration

Let $f:]0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous s.t. $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x),$
exist. Set $\hat f$ the continuous extension of $f$. I.e. $\hat f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is defined as $$\hat f(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)& x\in ]0,1]\\ \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)&x=0\end{cases}.$$

We know that $\hat f$ is integrable. Prove that $f$ is integrable over $]0,1]$ and that $$\int_0^1 \hat f=\int_{0^+}^1 f.$$

For the integrability, we have to check that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{t}^1 f(x)dx,$$
exist. But $$\int_t^1|f|=\int_t^1|\hat f|\leq \int_0^1|\hat f|,$$
and thus $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1 |f|,$$
exist, and thus $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1f=:\int_{0^+}^1 f,\tag{E}$$
exist.

**Q1) Is this correct ?**

**Q2) How can I prove that $$\int_{0^+}^1 f=\int_0^1|\hat f| \ \ ?$$**

To me it come from the fact that $\int_t^1 |f|=\int_t^1|\hat f|$ for all $t$. But in my solution they do as follow : suppose WLOG $f\geq 0$ $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\hat f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\frac{\hat f(0)}{n}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(\frac{k}{n}),$$
and thus $$\int_0^1\hat f=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_{0^+}^1 f.$$

Why doing such a thing ? I dont really understand the last equality... but is my equation (E) wrong ?

Comment: No, that proof is not correct. The integrals of $f$ and of $|f|$ don't have to be equal. Try looking at $\left|\int_{0}^{1}\hat{f} - \int_{t}^1f\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{t}\hat{f}+\int_{t}^{1}\hat{f} - \int_{t}^1f\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{t}\hat{f}+\int_{t}^{1}f - \int_{t}^1f\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{t}\hat{f}\right|\leq\max_{[0,t]}|hat{f}|\cdot |t-0|\leq\max_{[0,1]}|\hat{f}|\cdot|t-0|$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler approach. Since the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\t&\mapsto&\displaystyle\int_t^1\hat f(x)\,\mathrm dx\end{array}$$is continuous, you have\begin{align}\int_0^1\hat f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_t^1\hat f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_t^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_{0^+}^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}

Comment: This is not a proof. The continuity of that function is exactly what is required to be proven.

Comment: @cactus: We can extend $t\mapsto\int_t^1f(x)dx$ by continuity. So it work.

Comment: Since $\hat f$ is continuous, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that that function is differentiable. Since it is differentiable, it is continuous. And, in fact, you can easily prove it directly, without using that theorem.

Comment: So my proof at the equation (E) work, right ?

Comment: @Peter Which integral are you working with?

Comment: @Peter The fact that $t\to\int_{t}^{1}f$ is continuous is a stronger than what you are required to proof. It is a true fact, but starting from it is assuming the conclusion. So, not a proof.

Comment: @cactus: I proved first that $t\longmapsto \int_t^1 f$ is continuous. Maybe you didn't read my didn't read my post ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I know I can prove it easily directly. I did it. The point is that this answer doesn't.

Comment: @Peter You most definitely didn't proof anything. The whole argument that you have in your post doesn't lead to any conclusion.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I said $$\int_0^1|\hat f|=\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1|\hat f|=\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1 |f|=\int_{0^+}^1 |f|,$$ and thus $$\int_0^1|\hat f|=\int_{0^+}^1|f|\implies \int_0^1\hat f=\int_{0^+}^1 f.$$ Is it fine for you ?

Comment: @Peter Would you please tell me which integral are you working with?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Sorry : Riemman.

Comment: @Peter The last $\implies$ is non-sense. Just take $\hat{f}=1$  and $f(x)=\\operatorname{sgn}(x-1/2)$. Then the hypothesis holds ($1=1$) and the conclusion doesn't ($1=0$).

Comment: @Peter I cannot see how can you *prove* $(\textrm E)$ since, for me, the RHS is, by definition, the LHS. If it is not, then how do you define it?

Comment: @cactus: In your example, $\hat f(x)\neq f(x)$ for $x\in (0,1]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Yes, my mistake. I wanted to says that $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1 f(x)$$ exist and $$\int_{0^+}^1 f=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1 f=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1\hat f=\int_0^1\hat f.$$

Comment: @Peter Exactly. To get the conclusion you want, you need a proper argument that uses the information that you are given. In the argument that you wrote you are not using them. If your proof were correct, it would work for functions that do not satisfy your assumptions. Anyway. I already showed that your argument is wrong, that this answer is incomplete, and above I gave a complete proof. If you still don't understand, then you are on your own.

Comment: @Peter Then I don't understand how is it that you proved that $\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_t^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ exists.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: We have that $$\int_t^1|f|=\int_t^1|\hat f|\leq \int_0^1|\hat f|$$ and thus $\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1|f|$ converge (since it upper-bounded and increasing). Therefore $\int_0^1 |f|$ exist, and thus so is $\int_0^1 f.$ Does it work ?

Comment: @Peter I don't see why it should work, although I don't have a counterexample at hand right now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is trivially wrong. You can take exactly that argument and apply it to the discontinuous example that I gave above. If it worked, it would prove $1=0$. The hypotheses need to be used. In no-where has he used that $f=\hat{f}$ on $]0,1]$ in that argument. He only used $|f|=|\hat{f}|$.

Comment: @cactus : What ?? I really miss something... Maybe you don't agree with $$\int_0^1|f|$$ exist $\implies \int_0^1 f$ exist, is it what your are trying to tell me ?

Comment: @cactus It seems that you're right.

Comment: @cactus: But in your example, $f$ is not continuous. In my assumption, $f$ is continuous... So your counter example is not really a counter example.

Comment: @Peter Yes. You really miss something. So, start from that premise and have your concerns first, not about what you are being told, but about what you yourself are saying. The worst kind of ignorant is the one that thinks that he isn't.

Comment: @cactus: Don't worry, I totally accept to be wrong :) But anyway, don't we have that : $\int_t^1 f=\int_t^1 \hat f$ for all $t$, and thus $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1 f=\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1\hat f=\int_0^1 \hat f \ \ ? $$ But anyway, for your counter example, just to mention something, your function $f$ is not continuous. So if $f$ continuous, then, don't you think that $\int_0^1|f|=\int_0^1|\hat f|\implies \int_0^1 f=\int_0^1\hat f$ ? By the way : thanks a lot for your time and your determination, that help very much :)